# Alamofire Post Request with nested JSON parameters

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

My Alamofire post request looks like this:

```
Alamofire.request("http://...", method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
         .responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in ... })
```

Everything works fine if my parameters are simple:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
]
```

I run into problems if my parameters contain a json object.

```
let address: JSON = [
    "street": "1234 Fake St",
    "city": "Seattle",
    "state": "WA"
]

let parameters: Parameters = [
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address": address
]
```

The Alamofire request is not performed and my application crashes.

Comment: What is `JSON` in `let address: JSON`?

Comment: @Mr.Bista I'm using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). `JSON` is a data type.

Comment: were u able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that Alamofire is trying to encode a parameter as json that is already a json object. Essentially, double-encoding causes the application to crash.

The solution I found was to decode the json parameter before performing the request using SwiftyJSON's `.rawValue`.

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address": address.rawValue
]
```

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#raw-object

Answer (score 1):

For those not using SwiftyJSON, the Parameters type accepts a Parameters type as well, like so:

```
let address: Parameters = [
    "street": "1234 Fake St",
    "city": "Seattle",
    "state": "WA"
]

let parameters: Parameters = [
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "address": address
]
```