# Set headers with nested key-value in Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I'm trying to set the headers of an Alamofire 4 request where the headers have a key whose value is another key-value pair. The swift compiler is happy with my header variables but Alamofire won't take them.

This is what I have:

```
 let subHeader = [
  "some-key": "some-value",
  "another-oey": "another-value"
  ]

let headers : [String: Any] = [
  "some-header-key": "some-header-value",
  "subdata": [subHeader]
  ]

// Upload data                  
Alamofire.upload(data,
   to: uploadurl,
   method: .put,
   headers: headers)
   .validate()
   .response { response in
   // Handle response
 }
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294012/alamofire-post-request-with-nested-json-parameters

Comment: @SivajeeBattina That sorta helps but not really b/c they are using a 3rd party lib `SwiftyJson`.

Comment: Yes. You don't want to use SwiftyJSon?

Comment: Please check this link as well: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/896

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Just an extra lib I don't need in my app for this one little thing seems wasteful. And thanks for that other link but I just tried it and same problem - doesn't work.

Comment: I think you want to use `parameters` instead of `headers`.

Comment: @DaveWeston Tried that too. Doesn't work.

Comment: What don't you pass one string-json-formatted value to your header's key, and in your backend deserialise it?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Because backend can only access headers in `subdata`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at [Alamofire's source](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Request.swift#L67), you can see `HTTPHeaders` is actually `[String: String]`. Basically, `Alamofire` expects `[String: String]` from you as `headers`.

What you can do is converting your `subheader` into `String` with `NSJSONSerialization` and pass it to `Alamofire`.

```
let dictData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: subheader)
let dictString = String(data: dictData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
print(dictString)
// Now use "dictString" instead of "subheader" in your "headers" dictionary
```

You can do error handling however you want, I used `!`s for simplicity.